# Remove single quote from string using php

Tags: php, str-replace

I have got few special characters in a string. I have removed most of them except couple of characters and those are

`‘` and `’`

This is not similar to `'` `'`. I copied the `’` character from the browser.

Now my code looks like

```
$BadWords = array(",","'",":","+","&","...","(",")","?","%",".","!",'"');
$slug = str_replace($BadWords,"",$str);
echo $slug;
```

Even if I include those 2 chars in the array it doesn't remove from the string.Probably something needs to do with html decoding or something like that?

Comment: If you can please explain me the reason of "downvoting" then that would be really great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these to your array like below and check

```
$special_quotes= array(chr(145),chr(146),chr(147),chr(148),chr(151)); 

$BadWords = array_merge($special_quotes,$BadWords);
```

Comment: if this helps you then accept this as answer,so it'll helpful for other people.all the best

Comment: Sure I will.One more character which I tried that is &amp; that is £. I put the '&amp;' inside badwords array but didn't work.

Comment: the char value of this `£` symbol is 163,so add one more `chr(163)` in array